# Decimal point and class in C++

Tags: c++, class, double

Can anyone explain why I do not get the same answer I pass a variable in a class? My code is

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class cl {
    double k;
public:
    cl(double g) { k = g; } 
    int get_k() { return k; }
};

int main()
{
    double T = 88.564;
    cl ob(T);

    double h = ob.get_k();
    cout << h << endl;
    cout << T;
}
```

I suppose to get 88.564 in both cases, but why when I pass the variable into the class I get output equal to 88. 
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You typoed the return type of `get_k`. With a sufficiently high warning level, [your compiler would have told you](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xRehxO4PPu6UFDXc). Good job on the minimal example, though.

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question. That's pointless and _really_ confusing!

Comment: Don't fix the code in the question. It invalidates the answer and makes the question meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

Because

> ```
> int get_k() { return k; }
> ```

(which should be `const`-qualified) returns an `int`eger. Try

```
double get_k() const { return k; }
```

Also you should use the constructors member initializer list instead of copying in the constructors body:

```
cl(double g) : k{ g }
{}
```